# Spring WebSocket : getting error while writing data to the socket

Tags: spring-websocket

I am trying to implement spring websocket in my project, In which I have a scheduler which keeps on running for every 20 seconds and emit some data to connected sockets. Also, the default SockJS heartbeat  is configured to run for every 10 seconds to keep the connection alive

```
    @Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint(ApplicationConstants.STOMP_MESSAGE_GROUP_PREFIX,
            ApplicationConstants.STOMP_MESSAGE_ONETOONE_PREFIX).setHandshakeHandler(getHandler())
            .addInterceptors(new OneToOneStompMsgChannelInterceptor()).setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS().setHeartbeatTime(5000);
}
```

the problem is ,after running for sometime I am getting an error  like below

```
    DEBUG [MessageBrokerSockJS-3] o.s.w.s.s.t.s.WebSocketServerSockJsSession [AbstractSockJsSession.java:363] Terminating connection after failure to send message to client java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state [TEXT_PARTIAL_WRITING] which is an invalid state for called method
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.checkState(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1177)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase$StateMachine.textPartialStart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:1135)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.sendPartialString(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:226)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointBasic.sendText(WsRemoteEndpointBasic.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketSession.sendTextMessage(StandardWebSocketSession.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.AbstractWebSocketSession.sendMessage(AbstractWebSocketSession.java:105)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.writeFrameInternal(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.writeFrame(AbstractSockJsSession.java:325)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.sendMessageInternal(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.sendMessage(AbstractSockJsSession.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.tryFlushMessageBuffer(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:99)
at com.visionit.statchat.stomp.CustomStompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(CustomStompSubProtocolHandler.java:31)
at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:313)
at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75)
at com.visionit.statchat.stomp.WebSocketSessionCapturingHandlerDecorator.sendToAll(WebSocketSessionCapturingHandlerDecorator.java:201)
at com.visionit.statchat.service.impl.RedisMessageListener.pingClients(RedisMessageListener.java:89)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

it looks like both are trying to write data at same time.

is there any way to customize the SockJS heartbeat handler and let it use the custom handler which scheduler is using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported as bug in spring websocket framework .Here is the link https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14564